# joomla article edit

Tags: joomla, article

I am new in joomla 1.5.26 . I am trying to edit some certain articles for registered user but not for all articles. In my current situation all articles are becoming editable. But I want to make some of the articles would be editable. 
Please guide me how to do that.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to allow your users to edit only a kind of articles, you need ACL.
Sadly, there is no such thing in Joomla 1.5 (unless you buy a commercial extension), but you can find it natively in Joomla 2.5

It's a very powerful thing, give it a try!

**EDIT**
If you REALLY need to use joomla 1.5, take a look at [this component](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/backend-a-full-access-control/6799) : it adds the ACL logic inside site. I never tested it, however [here](http://extensions.joomla.org/search?q=acl) you can find more ACL extensions

Comment: but all other modules and component have been implemented in joomla 1.5 . Now in this scenario, only for editing  certain articles by registered user, shall I change the version from 1.5 to 2.5?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit any article from admin panel by logging in as Admin. In case you are logging in frontend with admin account then you can edit all articles,any other register user can not edit thees articles, this functionality is available for admin only.